# How to cast a string that contains a list to <Class 'List'>

Tags: python

I'm having trouble casting the data in varibale foo (str) to a List object in Python v3.7.2, is there a easy way to do it?

```
foo = "[{'ID': 6622, 'Status': 'Invoice processed'}]"
type(foo) # str
```

Comment: the best way is to declare it normally and write that without parentheses

Comment: Yes i'm actualy defragmenting, the real struggle was that this value is recieved from sys.argv[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval(foo)` or `literal_eval` is the most flexible way to do this as recommended in the other answer.

The alternative is, if your string is valid JSON, using `json.loads(foo)`, but would require that the string is valid JSON (double quotes around the key names)

```
import json
foo = '[{"ID": 6622, "Status": "Invoice processed"}]'
bar = json.loads(foo)
# bar == [{"ID": 6622, "Status": "Invoice processed"}]
```

then you can convert it back to a string:

```
import json
foo = [{"ID": 6622, "Status": "Invoice processed"}]
bar = json.dumps(foo)
# bar == '[{"ID": 6622, "Status": "Invoice processed"}]'
```

Comment: This is a complete answer; as i commented, the real problem is that i recieved this value from sys.argv[], thanks this will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval()`.

```
foo = literal_eval("[{'ID': 6622, 'Status': 'Invoice processed'}]")
```